# How to find all divs whose class starts with a string in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In BeautifulSoup, if I want to find all div's where whose class is span3, I'd just do:

```
result = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"span3"})
```

However, in my case, I want to find all div's whose class starts with span3, therefore, BeautifulSoup should find:

```
<div id="span3 span49">
<div id="span3 span39">
```

And so on...

How do I achieve what I want? I am familiar with regular expressions; however I do not know how to implement them to beautiful soup nor did I find any help by going through BeautifulSoup's documentation.

Comment: I haven't used BeautifulSoup but it seems to me the documentation is actually [pretty clear on this point](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class): "As with any keyword argument, you can pass class_ a string, **a regular expression**, a function, or `True`."

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well, these are `id` attributes you are showing:

```
<div id="span3 span49">
<div id="span3 span39">
```

In this case, you can use:

```
soup.find_all("div", id=lambda value: value and value.startswith("span3"))
```

Or:

```
soup.find_all("div", id=re.compile("^span3"))
```

---

If this was just a typo, and you actually have `class` attributes start with `span3`, and your really need to check the class to start with `span3`, you can use the "starts-with" [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select("div[class^=span3]")
```

This is because you cannot check the `class` attribute the same way you checked the `id` attribute because `class` is special, it is a [multi-valued attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes).

Comment: @GeorgeStack and make sure you are using `beautifulsoup4`: your import should be `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Do you mean doing this for the class:
**for a in soup.select("div[class^=span3]"):**
   #do the shit

Comment: @GeorgeStack yeah, exactly.

Comment: @aIecxe Did you learn this from the docs:
`id=lambda value: value and value.startswith("span3")`?

 I just learned that you can use this type of callable with `text` (as well it seems), but didn't find anything in the docs regarding this usage (only checked `text` though)

Answer (score 15):

This works too:

```
soup.select("div[class*=span3]") # with *= means: contains
```