# How to do a partial conditioning on a tag for find_all() in bs4?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have an xml which has multiple tags which look like this:

`<textblock height="55" hpos="143" id="Page1_Block5" lang="en-US" stylerefs="StyleId-E6BF91A3-3D6A-442F-9A46-22A0459A02E9- font1" vpos="226" width="393">`

I want to get all the `<textblock>` tags clustered by a Page (`id` property in the `textblock` tag). However, my id is written in the following way: `id="Page1_Block5"`.

However, I want to condition only on the Page number, and not the block number. (I want all blocks of a specific page).

I am trying to do the same via:

```
xml_soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(table, 'lxml')

text_blocks = xml_soup.find_all('textblock')
```

What more parameters would I need to add inside my `find_all()` function to be able to condition my results only on the `Page{}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help u:

```
text_blocks = xml_soup.find_all('textblock', id = lambda value: value and value.startswith("Page1"))
```

This is my entire code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = """
<textblock height="55" hpos="143" id="Page1_Block5" lang="en-US" stylerefs="StyleId-E6BF91A3-3D6A-442F-9A46-22A0459A02E9- font1" vpos="226" width="393">
"""

xml_soup = BeautifulSoup(xml,'lxml')

text_blocks = xml_soup.find_all('textblock', id = lambda value: value and value.startswith("Page1"))
```

**Explanation:**

The lambda function checks whether the `id` starts with `Page1`. If yes, then it retrieves the tag. I have also added few more values to the `xml` variable. Here is the test data that I used:

```
xml = """
<textblock height="55" hpos="143" id="Page1_Block5" lang="en-US" stylerefs="StyleId-E6BF91A3-3D6A-442F-9A46-22A0459A02E9- font1" vpos="226" width="393">
<textblock height="55" hpos="143" id="Page1_Block4" lang="en-US" stylerefs="StyleId-E6BF91A3-3D6A-442F-9A46-22A0459A02E9- font1" vpos="226" width="393">
<textblock height="55" hpos="143" id="Page2_Block5" lang="en-US" stylerefs="StyleId-E6BF91A3-3D6A-442F-9A46-22A0459A02E9- font1" vpos="226" width="393">
<textblock height="55" hpos="143" id="Page1_Block1" lang="en-US" stylerefs="StyleId-E6BF91A3-3D6A-442F-9A46-22A0459A02E9- font1" vpos="226" width="393">
"""
```

As u can see, there are 3 `textblock` tags with an `id` that starts with `Page1`. When I ran my code using this test data and printed out the length of the variable `text_blocks`, this is the output that I got:

```
>>> len(text_blocks)
3
```

This shows that the code works! Hope that this helps!

P.S: U can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465182/how-to-find-all-divs-whos-class-starts-with-a-string-in-beautifulsoup) link for more details about extracting elements with an `id` that starts with a particular string.