# How to find the string offsets in xml using bsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup

I have an xml file which is output for Abby's OCR software.

The xml content can contain multiple text blocks and also multiple table blocks (As the OCR'd document looks similar to a research paper which contains paragraphs of text with some tables in between those paragraphs)

I am trying to extract the text from tables, which looks like this in the xml:

```
<ComposedBlock ID="Page1_Block4" HEIGHT="240" WIDTH="1170" VPOS="226" HPOS="143" TYPE="table">
                        <TextBlock ID="Page1_Block5" HEIGHT="55" WIDTH="393" VPOS="226" HPOS="143" LANG="en-US" STYLEREFS="StyleId-E6BF91A3-3D6A-442F-9A46-22A0459A02E9- font1">
                            <TextLine HEIGHT="33" WIDTH="178" VPOS="234" HPOS="154">
                                <String CONTENT="some text" HEIGHT="33" WIDTH="178" VPOS="234" HPOS="154"/>
                            </TextLine>
                        </TextBlock>
```

The non-table text is present as part of text blocks, an example below:

```
<TextBlock ID="Page1_Block1" HEIGHT="52" WIDTH="1918" VPOS="3101" HPOS="148" STYLEREFS="StyleId-4CD32088-9994-4ED5-BD2B-8082FC83356D- font1" LANG="en-US">
                    <TextLine HEIGHT="42" WIDTH="1362" VPOS="3101" HPOS="154">
                        <String CONTENT="Mafi" HEIGHT="32" WIDTH="74" VPOS="3101" HPOS="154"/>
                        <String STYLE="bold" CONTENT="," HEIGHT="10" WIDTH="4" VPOS="3129" HPOS="235"/>
                        <SP HEIGHT="36" WIDTH="18" VPOS="3103" HPOS="240"/>
</TextLine>
</TextBlock>
```

Now, my problem statement is:  **How do I get the global offsets for only the text in the tables?**

This is how my code looks like for extracting text from tables:

```
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
page_definition = "Page" + str(page) + "_"
tables = soup.find_all('composedblock',{"type": "table"}, id=lambda value: value and value.startswith(page_definition))
for table in tables:
    table_content = []
    vpos = []
    # Converting table xml to str for bs4 to be able to consume
    table = str(table)
    xml_soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(table, 'lxml')
    # Finding all <textblock> tags inside the table ComposedBlock
    text_blocks = xml_soup.find_all('textblock')
    
    # Looping over all text blocks inside the table
    for text_block in text_blocks:
        print(table.text.index(text_block.text))
        # Getting all vpos numbers, as different vpos signify different rows ..
        # .. due to the virtue of vertical positions
        vpos.append(text_block.get("vpos"))

    # Collecting all vpos of a table
    all_vpos = set(vpos)
    all_vpos = sorted(list(all_vpos))
    for vpos in all_vpos:
        txt_block_row = xml_soup.find_all("textblock", {"vpos": str(vpos)})

        # Finding all text in a single
        row = []
        for txt_block in txt_block_row:
            texts = txt_block.findAll("string")
            content_text =[]
            for text in texts:
                content = text.get('content')
```

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail? "global offset" means "VPOS" of `<ComposedBlock>` with `type="table"`> o "VPOS" of `<String>` inside?

Comment: @AndrejKesely By global offset, I mean the index of the text inside the `< String >`, but from a global perspective.  

Example: The starting index of a text inside a `String` tag can be 52

^ Did this make it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question right. You want to print all indices of string that are inside table:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
<TextBlock ID="Page1_Block1" HEIGHT="52" WIDTH="1918" VPOS="3101" HPOS="148" STYLEREFS="StyleId-4CD32088-9994-4ED5-BD2B-8082FC83356D- font1" LANG="en-US">
    <TextLine HEIGHT="42" WIDTH="1362" VPOS="3101" HPOS="154">
        <String CONTENT="Mafi" HEIGHT="32" WIDTH="74" VPOS="3101" HPOS="154"/>
        <String STYLE="bold" CONTENT="," HEIGHT="10" WIDTH="4" VPOS="3129" HPOS="235"/>
        <SP HEIGHT="36" WIDTH="18" VPOS="3103" HPOS="240"/>
    </TextLine>
</TextBlock>

<ComposedBlock ID="Page1_Block4" HEIGHT="240" WIDTH="1170" VPOS="226" HPOS="143" TYPE="table">
    <TextBlock ID="Page1_Block5" HEIGHT="55" WIDTH="393" VPOS="226" HPOS="143" LANG="en-US" STYLEREFS="StyleId-E6BF91A3-3D6A-442F-9A46-22A0459A02E9- font1">
        <TextLine HEIGHT="33" WIDTH="178" VPOS="234" HPOS="154">
            <String CONTENT="some text" HEIGHT="33" WIDTH="178" VPOS="234" HPOS="154"/>
        </TextLine>
    </TextBlock>
</ComposedBlock>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

all_strings = []
are_we_inside_table = []
current_index, indexes = 0, []
for s in soup.select('string[content]'):
    all_strings.append(s['content'])
    are_we_inside_table.append(bool(s.find_previous('composedblock', type='table')))
    indexes.append(current_index)
    current_index += len(s['content'])

for s, t, i in zip(all_strings, are_we_inside_table, indexes):
    if t:
        print(i, s)
```

Prints:

```
5 some text
```

---

`5` because `Mafi` and `,` are strings but not inside table.

---

EDIT: To limit the search only on string on page 1, you can do thins change:

```
...
for s in soup.select('[id^="Page{}"] string[content]'.format(1)):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej. That was super helpful.  Is there a way to limit my search only to a specific page? Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64279200/4993513

Comment: @Dawny33 See my edit. You can do the change in CSS selector in for loop.