# find tags contain partial strings in text

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
<div id="a">123 456</div>
<div id="b">456</div>
<div id="c">123 456 789</div>

soup.findAll('div', text = re.compile('456'))
```

Only returns div b, no others.

```
soup.findAll('div', text = re.compile('45'))
```

Only returns div b, no others.

How to return other DIVs actually partially matches the specific string?

Comment: Do you just want the text between divs? why are you using regex?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all divs who's class starts with a string in BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465182/how-to-find-all-divs-whos-class-starts-with-a-string-in-beautifulsoup)

Comment: not limited to regex, I just want to find the divs whose text partially match specific strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is almost similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35465898/12309808). All you have to do is to tweak the `lambda` function a bit. Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div id="a">123 456</div>
<div id="b">456</div>
<div id="c">123 456 789</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

divs = soup.find_all("div", text=lambda text: text and '456' in text)
```

Output:

```
>>> divs
[<div id="a">123 456</div>, <div id="b">456</div>, <div id="c">123 456 789</div>]
```