# Change of class prevents find

Tags: beautifulsoup

Currently using the below to scrape a local web page for flood information but because the top two rows have gone to 'danger' the class has slightly changed. It's not "row border py-2 bg-success" anymore it's  "row border py-2 bg-danger" and there's probably a  "row border py-2 bg-warning" as well to take into account as an edge case. How can I please look for  "^row border py-2 bg-"? I was hoping ^ would work as begins with but it doesn't seem to! Thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://nosearmy.com/isitflooded/"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "row border py-2 bg-success"})


print g_data[0].text
print g_data[1].text
print g_data[2].text
print g_data[3].text
print g_data[4].text
print g_data[5].text
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all divs who's class starts with a string in BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465182/how-to-find-all-divs-whos-class-starts-with-a-string-in-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my ans as the best ans. Can u also upvote my ans? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a simple `lambda` function:

```
g_data = soup.find_all("div", class_ = lambda x: x and x.startswith('row border py-2 bg-'))
```

Or you can also use `regex`:

```
import re 
g_data = soup.find_all("div", class_ = re.compile('^row border py-2 bg-'))
```