# FInd_all in bs4 returns one elment when there is more in the web page in

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing web scrapping to a new egg page and i want to scrape the rating of the product by the consumers and i am using this code

```
page = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/msi-geforce-rtx-3060-rtx-3060-ventus-2x-12g-oc/p/N82E16814137632?Description=gpu&cm_re=gpu-_-14-137-632-_-Product').text
soup = bs(page , 'lxml')
the_rating = soup.find_all( class_ = 'rating rating-4')
print(the_rating)
```

And it returns only this one element even though I am using the find all element

```
[<i class="rating rating-4"></i>]
```

Comment: There's only that one element that has a class attribute containing *both* rating and rating-4 though...

Comment: this is just an example all of the ratings return one elment even the rating rating-5 elment that is the thing that i seem not understand?/

Comment: @majduddinalboon I got the recaptha with your code, but, if you manage to get the data, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35465898/12511801)

Answer (score 0):

I get `[]` with your code; judging by [the text content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K26WJ.png), or when I break it print the response status and url

> ```py
> r = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/msi-geforce-rtx-3060-rtx-3060-ventus-2x-> 12g-oc/p/N82E16814137632?Description=gpu&cm_re=gpu-_-14-137-632-_-Product')
> print(f'<{r.status_code} {r.reason}> from {r.url}')
> # soup = bs(r.content , 'lxml')
> ```

> output:
>
> ```
> <200 OK> from https://www.newegg.com/areyouahuman?referer=/areyouahuman?referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.newegg.com%2Fmsi-geforce-rtx-3060-rtx-3060-ventus-2x-12g-oc%2Fp%2FN82E16814137632%3FDescription%3Dgpu%26cm_re%3Dgpu-_-14-137-632-_-Product&why=8&cm_re=gpu-_-14-137-632-_-Product&Description=gpu
> ```

It's been redirected to a CAPTCHA...

---

Anyway, even if you get past that (I couldn't so I just pasted and parsed the response from my browser's [network logs](https://support.happyfox.com/kb/article/882-accessing-the-browser-console-and-network-logs/) to test), all you can get from `page` is the source HTML, which **[does not contain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgpd5.png)** any elements with `class="rating rating-4"`; using [selenium](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/2f8ad15efe25) and waiting for the page to finish loading yielded a [bit more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMgtk.png), but even then there weren't any exact matches.

<sup>[There were some matches when I inspected in browser, but **only if I wasn't in incognito mode**, which is likely why selenium didn't find them either.]</sup>

So, the site probably adds or removes some classes based on the source of the request. If you just want to get all elements with both the `rating` and `rating-4` classes (that will include the elements with **`class="rating is-large rating-4"`**), you can use `.find...` with [`lambda`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) (or define [a separate function](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#a-function)) or use [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) like

```py
the_rating = soup.select('.rating.rating-4') # shorter than 
# .find_all(lambda t: {'rating', 'rating-4'}.issubset(set(t.get('class', []))))
```

[Just make sure you have the full/correct HTML.]